# Call a method passing a parameter inside jsp with struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts-action

I have a scenario where I need to call a method of an Action class.
Below is the code.

```
<s:if test="#session['EXECUTOR'] != null">  
<tr>
    <td width="80%">
    Test: 
    <!-- <s:property value="#moveETHAction_fetchExecutorData(#session['EXECUTOR'])" /> -->
    <s:push value="#moveETHAction_fetchExecutorData(#session['EXECUTOR'])">
         <s:property value="top">
    </s:push>
    </td>
</tr>   
</s:if>
```

However it's not working, throwing some Jasper Exception -" **According to TLD, tag s:property must be empty, but is not**"

How do i call the method and return a `String` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't it be:

```
<s:property value="top"/>
```

in stead of

```
<s:property value="top">
```